# PhpStorm -> AngularJS support in Jade

Tags: angularjs, pug

**Is there any way to add/edit/create** AngularJS support in the Jade template?

I have installed *AngularJS and Jade plugin*, but I think Jade plugin doesn't have such a functionality.

Please take a look at the screenshot:

[image]

PhpStorm version : the latest PhpStorm 2016

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to what we're doing in vue.js now, even though it's a few years after you asked this question.  It works very well once you figure out the nuances.

If there was some way to turn off error checking, this pug statement:

```
{{"test"}}
```

would output an HTML tag with that as the tag name.

```
<{{"test"}}></{{"test"}}>
```

Of course, pug knows that this isn't a valid html tag name and throws an error - this is what happened in my test.pug when I tried your code:

```
1| html    
2| body
3|   {{\"test\"}}\n
---------^
unexpected text \"{{\"te\""
```

To solve this you'll need to create some type of tag to host your Angular template.  Spans work really well for inline text:

```
span {{"test"}}
```

will output:

```
<span>{{"test"}}</span>
```

You can also use the pipe character to just output the raw text following it:

```
| {{"test"}}
```

No matter what, you just need to add something to the start of that line and it will work as you want it to.